# Having jqgrid return a link based on the value of the data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqgrid

I have the following grid defined:

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
    url:'listOpenQueryInXML.php',
    datatype: 'xml',
    colNames:['Id','name1', 'name2', 'status', 'type'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'id', index:'id', editable: false, formatter:'showlink', formatoptions:{baseLinkUrl:'continue.php'}},
        {name:'name1', index:'name1', editable: false},
        {name:'name2', index:'name2', editable: false},
        {name:'status', index:'status', editable: false},
        {name:'type', index:'type', editable: false}
    ],
    autowidth: true,
    sortname: 'id',
    viewrecords: true,
    pager: null,
    sortorder: 'id',
    loadonce: false,
    caption: 'Open Query',
    height: '100%',
    xmlReader: { root : "rows", row: "row", repeatitems: false, id: "id" },
```

Now, what I would like to have is to override continue.php to be a different link based on the content of 'id', or 'status' or any field.

So if

status = NEW  link="new.php?id="{id}" 
status = STUCK link="helper.php?id={id}"

Etc.

I'm running jqGrid 4.3.1 and jQuery 1.8.16.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter) instead of `showlink` formatter. In the case you have to construct `<a>` element yourself based on the `cellvalue`, `options` and `rowObject` parameters of the callback function. Because you use `datatype: 'xml'` the `rowObject` parameter will be `IXMLDOMElement` so to get contain of the `status` you should use [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) or [children](http://api.jquery.com/children/) jqGrid method.

I don't tested the code below, but I suppose you can do something like the following

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
    url: 'listOpenQueryInXML.php',
    colNames: ['Id', 'name1', 'name2', 'status', 'type'],
    colModel :[
        {name:'id', formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                return '<a href="' +
                           ($(rowObject).children('status').text() === 'NEW' ?
                               'new.php' : 'helper.php') +
                           '?id=' + cellvalue + '">' + cellvalue + '</a>';
            },
        {name:'name1'},
        {name:'name2'},
        {name:'status'},
        {name:'type'}
    ],
    autowidth: true,
    gridview: true, 
    sortname: 'id',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: 'id',
    caption: 'Open Query',
    height: '100%',
    xmlReader: { repeatitems: false, id: "id" }
});
```

Its only an example of the formatter. You can place for example other text in the link which will be displayed the user.

I removed from the jqGrid definition which you use many default options and added the `gridview: true` options which improves the performance of the grid.